# Shell script $ANDROID usage

Tags: android, adb

I've been trying to execute a [shell script](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/downloads/detail?name=asl-1.2.zip&can=2&q=) in my application.

One of the first condition in the script is:

```
if [ -z $ANDROID ]; then
    echo "*** Android SDK not found ***"
    echo "Make sure the ANDROID variable is pointing to Android SDK root directory"
else
    adb="$ANDROID/platform-tools/adb"
...
```

If I run this script in script in one of my device is executes perfectly. But on there device it fails on `if [ -z $ANDROID ];`.

Now I wanted to know what is the purpose of `$ANDROID` & how come it is working on one phone(ver.2.3.5) and not on other(ver 4.1)?

Also please suggest if you know how to fix this script.

Thank You